# Offline and account-less notes and calendar apps for iOS

Tags: software-recommendation, calendar, notes.app

Are there any calendar and notes apps for the iPhone (iOS 12.4) that don't require syncing, cloud use, or an account with a supplier? I have not been able to find any, but I hope some exist.

Comment: Why are you deleting stuff ? I had just answered it!

Comment: Why won't Notes and Calendar work?

Comment: Sorry, @ankiiiiiii - I took it into my head for some reason that it was a stupid question. But it isn't, really. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @ruffle it is were a stupid Q, you'd get downvotes, but it's okay not to be familiar with some OS at first. You can visit your question  and undelete if you wish[How to undelete (reinstall?) the Calendar and Notes apps (not their content) on iPhone (iOS 12.4)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367670/how-to-undelete-reinstall-the-calendar-and-notes-apps-not-their-content-on/367671#367671)

Comment: Why is this closed as unclear? Original poster clearly asked for offline calendar and notes apps for iPhone.

Comment: Please have a look at https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation on how to ask for software recommendations. If you edit the question please also explain why using Notes and Calendar with iCloud sync disabled doesn‘t solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Notes' app should work fine in a stand-alone mode. Its included with your iPhone. And I think the iPhone Calendar should not have any requirements either but I assume you've tried it.

Comment: Thanks for this. Notes does work as you say. Having deleted the icon for Calendar I have now installed the app again, or at least got it showing again. But on the menu for Settings | Calendar there is an item "Sync" which can be set at "All Events", "Events 2 Weeks Ago", etc., but not at "None".

Comment: @ruffle  turn off calendar iCloud. Same for notes. Why leave a sync feature at all?